# get rows count from django_tables2

Tags: django, django-templates, django-tables2

I'm new at django, and I need to get table row count (best it would be if before rendering table) of table which rendered with django table2 in my template

have some code like this:

```
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %} 
{% block content %}
    {% render_table  participations_table %}
{% endblock %}
```

and I want to render this table if there is at least 1 row in it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check if there are any rows using the table's `rows` attribute

```
{% if participations_table.rows %}
    {% render_table  participations_table %}
{% endif %}
```

In the django template, you can get the number of rows with the [`length`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#length) filter.

```
{{ participations_table.rows|length }}
```

Or in the view, simply

```
len(participations_table.rows)
```

Alternatively, you could decide to always display the table, and customize the [`empty_text`](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pages/api-reference.html#Table.Meta.empty_text) attribute which is displayed when the table is empty.

Comment: and also I need to get rows count